# Android app rejected saying "Not adhering to Permission policy"

Tags: android, geolocation, google-play

App rejected by play store saying that "Not adhering to Permission policy" and details below from play store:

```
Eligibility Issue
Background location access not declared
We detected that your app contains at least one feature that requests access to location in the background, however  your permission declaration form did not reflect this. Please log in to your Play Console to resubmit your location declaration form. You may either remove location in the background from your app or indicate that the usage is in the background.
```

Android manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Target sdk:30

Also we have submitted declaration form[image]

And **we are using FusedBasedLocationProvider to get the location when user in the foreground. We are starting the location fetch in onStart() and stopping location updates in onStop() methods of Activity lifecycle.**

Can anyone know why the app hasbeen rejected eventhough app not using location in the background?

Answer (score -1):

Submit a new version of the same app to production track with 100% rollout, your app will be reviewed again and if there is no problem it will be reinstated.

Comment: App has been rejected in the internal testing with above reason. AFAIK, we can not upload to the production until we fix internal testing rejection.